# Design a set of attributes

Tags: database-design, database

My boss gave me a bunch of requirements that I'm not pretty sure about how to design them in the DBMS. Basically the user has to describe an object defining its attributes in an old fashion way: "key"=>"value".
The problem is that the user has "free will" on choosing both keys and values so he can wrote whatever he wants about this object.
Now, this objects belongs, of course, to certain categories so, in my opinion, even with the *free will mode on* I don't think we should have more than 15/20 keys per category(=>object).

My boss told me to structure it in the following way (that's just the skeleton):

> Table **objects(id**[primary key]**,
>   name)**
>
> Table **pairs(id**[primary
>   key]**,obj_id**[foreign key to objects
>   table]**, key, value)**

But I'm not really convinced. In my opinion it should be something like this:

> Table **objects(id**[primary key]**,
>   name)**
>
> Table **pairs(id**[primary
>   key]**,obj_id**[foreign key to objects
>   table]**, key_id**[foreign key to keys
>   table]**, value)**
>
> Table **keys(id**[primary key]**,
>   key**[unique]**)**

And of course the column `key` will be sanitized and redundancy will be limited.

Am i right, am I overthinking it or am I just wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think you're both wrong. I would go with:

```
Objects 
-------
id (PRIMARY_KEY)
name

Keys
----
id (PRIMARY_KEY)
value

KeyValuePairs
-------------
id (PRIMARY_KEY)
keyId (FOREIGN_KEY(Keys))
value

Objects_KeyValuePairs
---------------------
objectId (PRIMARY_KEY, FOREIGN KEY (Objects))
kvpId (PRIMARY_KEY, FOREIGN KEY (KeyValuePairs))
```

Now you have a table to store the Key/Value pairs ("key" => "value"), a table to store the parent, and a table to store the many/many relationship that Key/Value pairs may have with Objects.

Comment: Ok but the thing about "key" => "value" is that "key" is really common (as I said 20 keys at most). Value could be anything so I'll have a lot of redundancy for the column _key_ and none for _value_. What I've done with my solution is to limit the redundancy of keys. Wasn't that clear? I'll edit the question.

Comment: Yep. I'll go with your solution. I missed the many/many relationship. I didn't consider it before. Thanks.